# extjs grid editor advance to next column

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to make a grid editor that will automatically advance to the next column after 5 characters are typed in the first column.  I've put together what I think is the right code for this, but the selected column keeps jumping back to the first one and clears the data that was entered.

Here is the grid that I'm using:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'idNumbers',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('priceStore'),
    plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', 
    {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        pluginId: 'idNumberGridEditor'
    })],
    columns: [
        { 
            header: 'Name',  
            dataIndex: 'idNumber',
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false,
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('idNumberStore'),
                displayField: 'idNumber',
                valueField: 'idNumber',
                typeAhead: true,
                allowBlank: false,
                forceSelection: true,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    keyup: function(combo, e, eOpts) {
                        if(combo.getValue().length==5)
                        {
                            //move to next control
                            if(!this.nowFive)
                            {
                                editPlugin = this.up().editingPlugin;
                                curRow = editPlugin.context.rowIdx;
                                curCol = editPlugin.context.colIdx;
                                editPlugin.startEdit(curRow, curCol + 1);
                                this.nowFive = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.nowFive = false;
                        }                 
                   }
                }
            }
        },
        { 
            header: 'Phone', 
            dataIndex: 'price',
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false,
                 xtype: 'numberfield'
            }
        }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            console.log(this);
            //this.editor.startEdit(1,1);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the full example:  http://jsfiddle.net/cFD9W/5/

Comment: I don't think that fiddle is the right one...

Comment: Fixed the link to jsfiddle

Comment: Why would you set forceSelection: true AND want people to automatically get to the next field after entering 5 characters? It is one or the other but not both, you want people to select something from the provided values(combobox) OR you let them type whatever the hell they want(textfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`startEdit`](http://dev.vm/ext-4.2/docs/#!/api/Ext.Editor-method-startEdit) will reset the edit state (it is intended to be used in conjunction with [`completeEdit`](http://dev.vm/ext-4.2/docs/#!/api/Ext.Editor-method-completeEdit) or [`cancelEdit`](http://dev.vm/ext-4.2/docs/#!/api/Ext.Editor-method-cancelEdit). What you want here is just to focus the next field, this way the edit state will be handled correctly by the plugin.

Here's a rewrite of your listener in that spirit ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFD9W/12/)):

```
keyup: function(combo, e, eOpts) {
    if(combo.getValue().length==5) {
        //move to next control
        if(!this.nowFive) {
            var editPlugin = this.up().editingPlugin,
            editor = editPlugin.getEditor(), // Ext.grid.RowEditor
            curCol = editPlugin.context.colIdx,
            currentField = editor.getEditor(curCol),
            nextField = editor.getEditor(curCol + 1);
            if (currentField) {
                // ensure the combo is collapsed when the field is blurred
                currentField.triggerBlur();
            }
            if (nextField) {
                // startEdit will reset the edit state... What we need
                // is simply to focus the field, the value will be
                // updated when the user clicks the "update" button.
                nextField.focus();
            }
            this.nowFive = true;
        }
    } else {
        this.nowFive = false;
    }                 
}
```

Finally, as already said by Akori, if you set `forceSelection` to true, the combo value will be forced to one that already exists in the store, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the getEditor function of the RowEditor.  This solution seems to work, however, I'm going to be hardcoding the current column in my code because I will actually have two fields that need to advance one after another.  Unless I manually update the RowEditor context, the current column won't be updated to the right place, but then if I do manually update it, it may skip to the wrong column if the user re-edits the first field.